# Can't convert SQL query to laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this query that will get how many user votes with each star number

```
SELECT stars, COUNT(*) AS rate FROM product_user where product_id = 1 GROUP BY(stars)
```

result of this query

```
stars | rate
_____________
 2    |  3
 5    |  4
```

but I can't convert it to `laravel` eloquent

this is my try but it gets an error

```
Product::find($id)->votes()->selectRaw('count(*) as rate, stars')
  ->groupBy('stars')
  ->get();
```

Error message

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'roya.users.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `users`.`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, count(*) as rate, stars, `product_user`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id`, `product_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `product_user`.`stars` as `pivot_stars`, `product_user`.`feedback` as `pivot_feedback`, `product_user`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `product_user`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `users` inner join `product_user` on `users`.`id` = `product_user`.`user_id` where `product_user`.`product_id` = 1 group by `stars`)
```

**Product Model**

```
class Product extends Model {
 public function votes()
 {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
            ->using('App\Review')
            ->select('users.id', 'first_name', 'last_name')
            ->withPivot(['stars', 'feedback'])
            ->withTimeStamps();
 }
}
```

Comment: Please can you show the relationship for votes and also the table definitions.

Comment: @Rwd check it again it's updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use grouped select queries SQL allows only for aggregated functions or columns specifically listed in `GROUP BY` section to be selected. Your `votes()` relationship adds extra select columns to your query (`'users.id'`, `'first_name'` and `'last_name'`) and they are causing an error. This happens because `selectRaw` method doesn't replace previously selected columns, but utilizes `addSelect()` method to add raw on top of the existing ones.

In your case it's really cumbersome to use Eloquent here when you only need an aggregated count data for specific product votes.

Just add `getVotesCountByStars` method to your `Product` model and utilize Laravel's generic query builder via `DB` facade:

```
public function getVotesCountByStars()
{
    return DB::table('product_user')
        ->where('product_id', $this->id)
        ->selectRaw('count(*) as rate, stars')
        ->groupBy('stars')
        ->orderBy('stars', 'asc')
        ->get()
        ->pluck('rate', 'stars')
        ->toArray();
}
```

This way you will see exactly what query is generated and no additional overhead is produced (in my example, an associative array with stars as keys and counts as values will be returned).

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is is add a `ratings` relationship to your Product model that is  a `hasMany` between `Product` and `Rating`:

```
public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Rating::class)
        ->select('stars', 'product_id')
        ->selectRaw('count(*) as rate')
        ->groupBy('stars', 'product_id');
}
```

Then your query would be something like:

```
$product = Product::with('rating')->find(1);
```

This would product something like:

```
{
   "id":1,
   ...
   "ratings":[
      {
         "stars":2,
         "product_id":1,
         "rate":1
      },
      {
         "stars":3,
         "product_id":1,
         "rate":2
      },
      {
         "stars":4,
         "product_id":1,
         "rate":4
      },
      {
         "stars":5,
         "product_id":1,
         "rate":3
      }
   ]
}
```